# No module name dj_database_url

Tags: python, heroku-postgres

I have installed dj_database_url in my project but it is still producing an error  when I do import dj_database_url.

> No module name dj_database_url

Here's what my code looks like:

```
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the executable which your code is using with:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

you will get path to executable. 
Now, install using command:

```
<path-to-python-executable>/python -m pip install dj_database_url
```